# How to add a pause between a discord.py bot joining a voice-channel?

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with discord.py. The bot is supposed to join the VC and wait lets say 5 minutes, then leave. For testing purposes, this number has been set to 2 seconds. Now the issue is, when the bot joins, the wait function is completley ignored. No matter what I set it to.

I've tried larger numbers but that wont work either.

```
#The part of the code I'm having trouble with:
try:
    vc = await ctx.guild.get_channel(int(chanid)).connect()
    time.sleep(2)
    await vc.disconnect()
except: 
    print(f"Action Failed: JoinVC.")
#Keep in mind, this is only part of the code.
```

I expect the bot to attempt to join the channel, and 2 seconds later, leave. I get no error messages when the code is run as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep` doesn't work well with asyncio, which discord.py is baded on. Try `await asyncio.sleep(3)` instead.